# Call plugin object from component in Vue.js 2 with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a plugin object for the regex I use in my app so I can use them in a global way. Something like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.prototype.$regex = { 
  //isEmail function here
}
```

In javascript this code works. However in my new typescript project once I do:

```js
methods: {
  isEmail(string: string): boolean {
    return this.$regex.isEmail(string)
  }
}
```

I get:

```
Property '$regex' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue...
```

What's the correct way of using my plugin in a Vue.js 2 with typescript project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, error happens because typescript does not know about your `$regex` in Vue's object prototype.

You can create file that will be included by typescript, for example `types.d.ts` in `src` directory, and put you type definition of `$regex`

```js
import Vue from "vue";

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  export interface Vue {
    $regex: { isEmail: (some: string) => bool }
  }
}
```

ref: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/648799021a890f652f6eb6dd96713cb811c3efa6/packages/vuetify/types/index.d.ts#L60

Comment: This almost worked. There is only one detail missing. You have to import Vue in the file like so: `import Vue from "vue";` otherwise it just won't work. That step isn't optional.